# get bound method from "obj.method" string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know that one can use `getattr` to get a method from just an object and a string, like

```
this_func = getattr(MyObj, 'method_name')
this_func(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, I have tried to go one beyond this and pass around "object.method" strings and get both the object and the method, and I haven't seen a reliable means of doing so.

For example, if I have a function like this:

```
def func_from_string(callstr):
    obj, meth = callstr.split('.') # turns 'obj.foo' into 'obj', 'foo'
    o = globals.get(obj)
    if o is not None:
        return getattr(o, meth)
```

...this only works when everything is in global scope. It fails if the object is created in a separate function.

```
def some_other_func():
    MyObj = SomeObject()
    f = func_from_string("MyObj.foo")
    f()
```

Doing the horrible-looking `globals().get("obj", locals().get("obj"))` doesn't change this outcome - `MyObj` isn't seen by `func_from_string`, so this just doesn't work.

It occurs to me that there may be a backdoor via `obj.meth.__self__`, but to do that I still have to get to the bound method somehow, and I'm not clear on whether or not I can do that without getting to the object first.

I might just be trying to do something a little *too* magical -- but is there a right way to use the *string* "MyObj" to get at the *instance* of `MyObj`, regardless of the scope it was created in?

Comment: The reason that this is awkward is that **it's a bad idea**. Names in Python are [just references to objects](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#python-has-names) - what if the `SomeObject` instance is only referenced in a list?

Comment: You mean like `mylist = [SomeObject(), OtherObject(), DanFielding()]`? Yeah I can see how that would get messy. I didn't say this would be a *great* idea :) I'm totes willing to abandon the thought if the whole thing is just too awkward - Python says "one right way" not "one right way, and a host of terrible ones"

Comment: And bear in mind that, in the scope you're calling `func_from_string` from, you *already have a direct reference to the instance*. It's not clear how you think it's an improvement over calling `getattr`, and the effort suggests that it isn't!

Comment: I'm agreeing with you, this does get too weird

Answer (score 0):

This is going to get ugly. `func_from_string()` can access the *parent* scope, by asking Python to return that frame with [`sys._getframe()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys._getframe):

```
import sys

def func_from_string(callstr):
    obj, meth = callstr.split('.')
    parent_scope = sys._getframe(1)
    o = parent_scope.f_locals.get(obj)
    if o is not None:
        return getattr(o, meth)
```

You really want to ask yourself why you are doing all this, however. There are usually better ways to handle dynamic object access, such as using an explicit dictionary.

Comment: "You really want to ask yourself why you are doing all this, however." Ohh I dunno, because I learn by doing. :/ As jonrsharpe has pointed out, there are reasons why this is not a good idea, which leads me to think there's a whole slew of other times when one would not want to actually do this, and one would rather implement something more direct. If it's ugly, I'm not interested in the practice, but I'll surely upvote the answer